# QGIS Essen vs Wien discrepency in saving tiff

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

In QGIS 2.8.4 Wien, when I right click a layer and save the rendered image with the create VRT option enabled, QGIS creates both a .vrt and .tif file.  However, when I do that in QGIS 2.14.0 Essen, only the .vrt is created and I'm not sure why the exact same steps produce different results in the versions.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Perhaps a bug has been fixed in a newer version. It you want to save into .vrt why should you get also .tif? If you need tif, save directly into tif or convert the vrt file into tif with gdal_translate.

Comment: I have a tif that apparently has some extra metadata and so gdal2tiles was failing to create any useful data.  When I saved it from Wien, I was able to import the resultant rendered image tif and use gdal2tiles without a problem.

Comment: Problem is, Wien doesn't link to the new version of GDAL which include the gdal2tiles tool, so I was hoping to do it all in Essen

Comment: What happens if you save the image without the VRT option checked?

Comment: Nothing.  No .tif is created.  It's just an empty directory